# i want to upload a background image in laravel but it is not showing on the website on the browser

Tags: css, image, frontend, background

this is the code in laravel; It is a blade file:

```
<!-- Page Header -->
<!-- Set your background image for this header on the line below. -->
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url{{asset('img blades/home-bg.jpg')}}">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="site-heading">

                    <h1>Clean Blog</h1>

                    <hr class="small">
                    <span class="subheading">A Clean Blog Theme by Start Bootstrap</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

i tried to add an image element  to see if the problem was the path of the image but it works perfectly so i don't understand where the problem is

Comment: Missing brackets/quotes for `url()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Answer (score -1):

Your

```
url{{asset('img blades/home-bg.jpg')}}
```

does not look good. First, you need to have quotes inside the `url` brackets, like `url('/some/path')`. Second, your call to `asset` also does not look good. You probably meant `'img/blades/home-bg.jpg'` instead of `'img blades/home-bg.jpg'`.